# Execute a stored procedure using an SqlDataAdapter in C#

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

How can i use an SqlDataAdapter to execute an sql stored procedure that contains statements which update one table and insert into another table, but returns no value?

**EDIT**:There are answers related to the execution of stored procedures with SELECT statements. However, that's not what i'm looking for.

Comment: Why not use SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the `SqlDataAdapter` to populate a `DataTable` or `DataSet` object.  If this is the case and you want the changes to the `DataTable`/`DataSet` to be persisted to your database and you require using stored procs then you'd need to set the [`UpdateCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand(v=vs.110).aspx), [`InsertCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.insertcommand(v=vs.110).aspx), and/or [`DeleteCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.deletecommand(v=vs.110).aspx) properties.

Example:

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM WHATEVER", connection);
adapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand()
{
    Connection = connection,
    CommandText = "EXEC myStoredProc",
    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
};
//Don't forget to set your parameters!
```

Otherwise if you don't need the adapter just use a SqlCommand and call [`ExecuteNonQuery()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If the statement returns no data, you wouldn't use a SqlDataAdapter.  Just use a SqlCommand and call [ExecuteNonQuery().](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)